# Are Chinese authorities jailing, harassing, and torturing legal activists?

Tags: china

> Reports suggest the authorities are not just jailing and harassing legal practitioners and their relatives, but also subjecting some of them to appalling torture.

The Economist | Champions chained: [China’s crushing of independent lawyers is a blow to rule of law](http://www.economist.com/news/leaders/21723420-why-xi-jinping-fears-experience-uppity-taiwan-chinas-crushing-independent-lawyers?frsc=dg%7Ce).

Comment: Not a good question, the claim is basically impossible to disprove. *Which activists*?

Comment: [Here's a list of jailed Chinese political activists on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Chinese_dissidents#Detained_and_jailed_people).  For the purposes of this question, what's torture?  This is, the people are already confined to small cages and stripped of their human rights; does malnutrition count, or is the interest in stuff like beatings?

Comment: Apparently China banned the use of evidence found by torture in court cases in 2010 (["China Bans Court Evidence Gained Through Torture"](https://www.nytimes.com/2010/06/01/world/asia/01china.html) (2010)).  This would seem to be official government recognition of the fact that there was evidence gathered through torture.

Comment: Most recently there was a crackdown in July 2015, known as the "710 Crackdown". The [Wikipedia entry](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AD%E5%9C%8B710%E3%80%8C%E7%B6%AD%E6%AC%8A%E5%BE%8B%E5%B8%AB%E3%80%8D%E5%A4%A7%E6%8A%93%E6%8D%95%E4%BA%8B%E4%BB%B6) (in Chinese) has an account of what happened to each lawyer and their families.

Comment: Found an English version [here](http://chrlawyers.hk/en/content/1700-7-august-2015-least-267-lawyers-law-firm-staffhuman-right-activists-have-been-detained).